# termui's termui.Handle("/timer/1s", func(e termui.Event)) not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: go

I'm working with golang and used **termui** library for a purpose. find ref [here](https://github.com/gizak/termui) for the library.

```
termui.Handle("/timer/1s", func(e termui.Event) {
    if true {
        if true {
            strs = []string{"something"}
        } else {
           strs = []string{"something else"}
        }
        ls.Items = strs // ls := termui.NewList()
    } else {
        strs = []string{"something else"}
        ls.Items = strs
    }
    termui.Render(ls)
})
```

above code is to suppose write a text on terminal window but nothing is happend. I've not got any ref or solution regarding same.
above code is working on windows but not in ubuntu 18.04.

also

```
termui.Handle("/sys/kbd/C-c", func(termui.Event) {
    termui.StopLoop()
})
```

above code working on windows but not in ubuntu 18.04.

Please provide a solution or alternatives for above.

thanks in advance.

Comment: strs = []string{"something else"}} last bracket is typo mistake while question writing

Comment: Hi. Instead of posting an errata inside a comment, you could just edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm answering my own question. Owner of library change their events and functions. They deprecated `/timer/1s` and force user to use `Go`s build in timer.
[here](https://github.com/gizak/termui) is library changes and [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gizak/termui)